# There is no largest rational number $p$ such that $p^2 < 2$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, rational-numbers

In Rudin's analysis example 1.1, he tried to show the following

Let $A$ be the set of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2<2$ and let $B$ consist of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2 > 2$. He show that $A$ contains no largest number and $B$ contains no smallest

More explicitly, for every $p$ in $A$ we can find a rational $q$ in $A$ such that $p < q$ and vice versa

He then shows

$$q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p + 2}$$

$$q^2 - 2 = \frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p + 2)^2}$$

and conclude that if $p$ in $A$ then $p^2 - 2 < 0 \rightarrow q^2 < 2$ and $q > p $ and vice versa.

I understand the conclusion, and I understand the hypothesis, but I didn't understand how he got

$$q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p + 2}$$

and

$$q^2 - 2 = \frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p + 2)^2}$$

Specifically, I think he is trying to show the following

If $p$ in $A$, let $q$ be a number greater than $p$

$$q = p + \beta$$

now show

$$q^2 - 2 < 0 \Rightarrow q^2 - 2 = p^2 + 2\beta p  + \beta^2 - 2$$

I use the quadratic equation to find the threshold for $\beta$, but I can't derive what Rudin give, can someone explain how Rudin got his equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that: $p^2 < 2 \Rightarrow p^2+2p < 2 + 2p \Rightarrow p(p+2) < 2+2p \Rightarrow p < \dfrac{2+2p}{p+2}\in \mathbb{Q}$. He then set $q = \dfrac{2+2p}{p+2}$, then $p < q$ from definition of $q$, and furthermore: $q^2 - 2 = \left(\dfrac{2+2p}{p+2}\right)^2 - 2= \dfrac{4+8p+4p^2}{p^2+4p+4} - 2= \dfrac{2}{(p+2)^2}\cdot (p^2-2) < 0\Rightarrow q^2< 2.$

Comment: Once you have the formula it is easy to verify the proof, but I think the question, as I understood it, is: how does he know this value of $q$, that is indeed larger than $p$, will suffice to produce the result of your last line. So where does the formula come from?

Comment: I know... Maybe this is it, but it still looks a bit artificial to me.  I mean: by the same logic, $p^2<2 \implies p < \frac{p+2}{1+p}$, $p<\frac{2+3p}{3+p}$, $p<\frac{2+p^3}{p+p^2}$  and a ton of other formulae. So why does this one work?

Comment: I'm still not sure, after reading your post, what the thought process could have been for this term. I can see that what you have written is true, but there's no exposition about the approach to choosing this term. I'm not sure whether I should open another question on this, or comment on those that are here, I'm doing the latter for now.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can see it the following way:

you are looking for a $\beta >0$ and rational such that $(p+\beta)^2 < 2$,
note that this means that necessarily $p+\beta < 2^{\frac{1}{2}}<2$ .

Now $(p+\beta)^2 < 2 \Leftrightarrow 2\beta p + \beta^2 < 2-p^2 \Leftrightarrow \beta< \frac{2-p^2}{p + p +\beta} $ but for any $\beta$ you are looking for, you have  $p+\beta <2$ and so $\frac{2-p^2}{p + 2}<\frac{2-p^2}{p + p +\beta}$. And so any $\beta \in ]0;\frac{2-p^2}{p + 2}]$ should be ok for what you want, you can therefore take $\beta = \frac{2-p^2}{p + 2}$.

Does it appears to you a little more natural now ?